# Extract app_id and user_id from Facebook Access Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I have the following access token:

**161551960578281**|2.AQDCjxLBWAwdLle6.3600.1311602400.0-**544419103231**|0L0tcyKgGA0WT3SPJ29CVXqChwk

From this access_token:

```
App_id = 161551960578281
```

and

```
User_id = 544419103231
```

Can someone provide an example on how to get those programmaticaly using Ruby / RoR.

**EDIT:**

Do not care if they will change the format in the future!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook access token server-side validation for iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406859/facebook-access-token-server-side-validation-for-iphone-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rely on that format being constant, you should use the access token linter at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/lint which will give you both fields.

Programmatically, you can determine the user ID via a graph API call:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN HERE]` - if the token is still valid you'll get back an answer like this:

```
{         
"id": "[UID HERE]"
}
```

I'm not sure of a good way to determine the app ID via an API call, but you should already have this since it's your app.

Comment: I do not care if they will change the access_token format in the future.. Unfortunately I cannot use /me.

Comment: Well the linter should give you both the user ID and app ID, but if you have a large number of tokens to check there may be a rate limit to stop people spidering that endpoint

Comment: Yes Linter is what I was looking for. But I want to do it programmatically so my only option at the moment is to split that access token.