# In spring social for Facebook api, why does facebook.isAuthorized always return true?

Tags: spring, spring-social

I have an angular2 app that has a Facebook login feature. When the user authenticates themself, I then send this accessToken to the server.

[image]

The server program is with Springboot and I make use of spring social.

I want to check to see if this user is authorized. So I call:
[image]

facebook.getToken() returns the access token generated on the client side. When I call facebook.isAuthorized() it returns true...As expected, because I am sending real data.

Although if I send bogus data such as:

[image]

(The token in this case is fabricated by me) to the same API endpoint
facebook.isAuthorized returns true. This is unexpected because in this case I am fabricating an accessToken.

The spring-social dependency is this:

[image]

Why does isAuthorize return true for a real access token, as well as a fake one? How can I check to see if a user of my angular2 app has authenticated themselves through Facebook on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of `isAuthorized()` for FacebookTemplate can be found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/a6bf2626ee8ac81765c416029ca033affc94fc6c/spring-social-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/oauth2/AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding.java#L87.

With this source its quite obvious that `isAuthorized()` only checks if there is any access token provided.

To validate your token you can run any request which need authorization (e.g. `userOperations().getUserPermissions()`) and check for `InvalidAuthorizationException` or you can find some inspirations in [how to verify facebook access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605703/how-to-verify-facebook-access-token).