# Facebook Login and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, authentication

When I use `Facebook Login` (JavaScript) on my website, I receive the user id from Facebook in the browser.

Secondly I want to fetch some data from the database using said user id.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE user_id = 123400000001;
```

How can I pass the id to PHP without the user being able to alter the id?

Comment: AJAX would be a possibility here.

Comment: What format do you receive the user id in? i.e. is it a cookie, is it JSON...etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from user ID, you also receive an [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens), which you can pass to your backend and use for the verification of the user (using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608017/942648), for instance).