# Facebook Login Flow, helping understand me the need for the debug token call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'm doing a facebook app and I've followed the custom login flow instructions and I have a question on the last step:

1) I start by doing a call to `/dialog/oauth` to get a login `code`.

2) With the code I will request an access token, by hitting the `graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` and that's fine as well.

3) The [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#checktoken) now say I should validate the `code` and `token` to make sure they are from the sources that requested them.

```
GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
     input_token={token-to-inspect}
     &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
```

My questions are:

- What is the input_token in my scenario?
- Do I need to do this in my flow? And why if yes?

If I just pass the same value(`access_token`) in both parameters I get a valid anwser but I don't know if this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you are doing login flow using the `code` parameter only, there is no need to do this. Have you requested a `token` parameter in your login dialog call …? If not, then there is nothing to worry about (apart from your skill in reading documentation _correctly_ …)

Comment: Btw., your question is tagged with `javascript` only, no server-side techniques mentioned – I hope that you are __not__ doing the exchange of `code` for an access token client-side …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has already been asked: [how to verify facebook access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605703/how-to-verify-facebook-access-token/8608017#8608017)

And: [Verify Facebook Access Token for specific App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543882/verify-facebook-access-token-for-specific-app/14544039#14544039)

And: [verification code example](https://gist.github.com/jaredhabeck/1628718)

It's simply a unit test to see if your code is still valid (to catch a bug early so it can't do any big damage).

If the access token is not valid, you can for example show a message to the user that there is a bug etc.

Comment: "It's simply a unit test to see if your code is still valid (to catch a bug early so it can't do any big damage)." - thanks