# Appmobi Codeigniter and Facebook SDK JavaScript vs PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, codeigniter

Ok, this isn't going to be the best quality question without a doubt. But I am looking for advice mostly on how to handle the next phase of an app I am developing. This is my first app in appmobi so things with it are a bit confusing to me still.

So generally speaking I am very used to working with PHP and sticking to browser based development. With that most of what I want to do with Facebook as far as the API's go for the graph I have done using the PHP FB-SDK. If your familiar with Appmobi then you know php is out well directly at least.

This app I am making, I have it working fine with everything else I am doing. I'm communicating with my server, people are logging in, people are registering, people are using the server for what its worth. But this Facebook bit has me stumpped. I want to offer facebook as a means of login/registration for my app, I want to post to facebook from my app pending a user approves it, and a handful of other things. But I dunno the best way to approach this through the app as its all static html based pages and javascript thus far.

So I am hoping someone will read through this all, and hopefully a handful of you that do, will know some means of doing what I want to do, Im not looking for someone to drop me a pile of code and give me the answer (nice as that would be). No I am just simply looking for what I should do to handle this between all the layers mentioned here to make this work. So I can start building this piece up.

Comment: There is a related question, which might be helpful to you, at least partially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507729/secure-communication-between-ios-client-facebook-api-and-server/11511325#11511325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Facebook, appMobi has recently added a Facebook object to the API you might use to be able to log into Facebook and access the Facebook Graph.  You can find the Facebook API documentation here:

http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/jsAPI/facebook/index.html

There is a supporting document illustrating how to set up things on Facebook's side that can be found here:

http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/index.php?DOC=FACEBOOK_INTEGRATION

I'll do my best to post some sample code as well.  I'm kind of working through the exact same thing.

Comment: Hmm, that jsAPI doc may come in handy. Through my normal googling I haven't found that one yet, Ill have to give that one a read, but seeing that in combination with the other doc which John gave me a link to the other day seems to make a bit more sense. But yea, if you can provide a sample also that would be doubly as awesome. Facebook has been a thorn in my side for a while, with or without appmobi, hopefully now seeing this it will be much easier for me to start making by, thank you

Comment: Chris, you can (at least temporarily) find a link to a sample Facebook implementation here: https://am-xdk.s3.amazonaws.com/app.81d8e283-d5ab-4097-bbf0-b17da0837c55/f1cb3231-0a64-468f-b5ef-822a72572930/QA/bundle.zip

Comment: wow, thats more than I could have hoped for in an example. Thanks. Also, between the doc's you provided and some additional help from searches I have managed to get some stuff working unfortunately its emulator side only as when I do test anywhere, when facebook launches (both on ios and android) I get an error, if you check out another post I made about that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926752/facebook-appmobi-debugging-when-theres-no-distinct-error you can see a screen shot of the error, the code thats with the post has since changed but the error remains the same.

Comment: been trying to figure out how to debug it, but facebooks developer tools are worthless, as are a couple other options I've tried like the iPhone Config Profiler tool.