# Login with oauth validate token

Tags: facebook, oauth, server, client

I want to create an app that will authenticate with my server using oauth.
My question is how will this work?

My client side will communicate using HTTPS with Facebook and get an Access Token. Then it should send it to my server side to authenticate? My server should save the token in the db? How it can validate the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**how will this work. ?**

When the client needs authorization to access some information about the user, the browser (user agent) redirects the resource owner to the OAuth authorization server. There, the user is faced with an authentication dialog (this dialog is not shown if the user is already authenticated), after which he or she is presented an authorization dialog explaining the permissions that the client is requesting, the information that it needs to access or the actions that it needs to do on his or her behalf.

**Access Token should send it to my server side to authenticate? or server should save the token in the db?**

From what you describe I'd suggest to use a server-side login flow.
-so that the token is already on your server, and doesn't need to be passed from the client. If you're using non-encrypted connections, this could be a security risk.

(after a user successfully signs in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity of the ID token and retrieve the user's ID from the sub claim of the ID token. You can use user IDs transmitted in this way to safely identity the currently signed-in user on the backend.)

-See

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#login

**How to validate token ?**

you can follow this link , you will get your step by step solution for an app.
[Facebook access token server-side validation for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406859/facebook-access-token-server-side-validation-for-iphone-app)