# can we retrieve Facebook leads without Facebook APP Review

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-webhooks

I have created an App in `https://developers.facebook.com/apps` and I have one Facebook page, in that I have created ads and I got some leads, those leads I can see in `Leads Center` in respective page.
So I need to retrieve this Leads into my server.
When I run this below API in browser excel file is downloading directly and I can see all my leads in that file https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=form.

By using my App(which I created in developer) done some setting and I created webhook for user,pages and permission, in permission I can see `lead_retrival, ad_reads` and I have tested, those tested leads are coming into my server by given webhook URL.

But how can I get my actual leads which is in Lead Center belongs to my page and is there any APIs are available ?

Is APP review necessary to retrieve leads from form or any other option(I tried Zapier but that is not I am looking for).

what I tried:
I am working on my server so I went through with this link [PHP cURL to verify Facebook API login access_token on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877083/php-curl-to-verify-facebook-api-login-access-token-on-server), and created all access tokens  by my app and I am getting `Success. Login is valid`
then I did not understand next what I have to do.

Can any one help on it please?

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Can any one respond on it please ?